# How to respect non-self-closing br tags when apex parsing HTML with "Dom.Document" class

Tags: apex, xml, parsing, xmlparsing

I'm trying to parse an HTML string. This string comes from a Salesforce rich text editor's content. It's a field saved on a record.

```
String html = '<p>hello<br>goodbye</p>'

String XML_DECLARATION = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
Dom.Document document = new Dom.Document();
document.load(XML_DECLARATION + html);
```

This raises the error:

> ERROR: System.XmlException: Failed to parse XML due to: end tag name </p>
> must match start tag name <br> from line 1

This appears to be because this string is treated as "xhtml+xml" or maybe just "xml" content type, despite the class name being `Dom.Document`. It's expecitng the `<br>` tag to have a paired closing tag, or be self closing.

I can do a find and replace on these, but I'm worried about other self closing tags. Is there a way to make the parser handle non-self-closing `<br>` tags without erroring?

I've tried wrapping the string in `<!DOCTYPE HTML><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...</html>` but that didn't have an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dom.Document, despite its namespace, **is** an XML parser. It is not meant to handle `<br>`, because XML doesn't allow it. You will need to find/replace all `<br>` with `<br/>`. Self-closing tags are just fine, e.g. `<hr/>`, as well as tags that are simply empty of content (`<p/>`).

Comment: Makes sense, and creates a chicken and egg problem of trying to parse xml before using it. For now i'm going to use `html.replaceAll('<(hr|br)\\s?>', '<$1 />'));`